# How do I insert a date/timestamp before the contents I'm trying to append to a text file with this simple .vbs?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I'm using this script to add text to a variety of .txt's on the fly:

```
Const ForAppending = 8

Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(objArgs(1)) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objArgs(1), ForAppending)
Else
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(objArgs(1))
End If

objFile.WriteLine objArgs(0)
objFile.Close
```

So I'm sending text with the program launchy this .vbs (addln.vbs) -

("$$" c:\ideas.txt) is what the argument is if I want to send to ideas.txt for example

All I want to do is make it so I get the date and time right before whatever text I send to this text file. I don't think this would be too complicated... thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this -

```
objFile.WriteLine Date() & " " & Time() & " " & objArgs(0)
```

Comment: Oooh, works perfectly! Thanks so much... Do you know if there's an easy way to truncate off the seconds display? 12/1/2011 9:29:27 AM that's what I'm seeing now and I'd ideally just want to see 9:29AM

Comment: `FormatDateTime(Time(),4)` should return a 24 hour time with no seconds but no AM/PM either. I think that's the best you can do without manual parsing. Could you please accept the answer if it has helped. Thanks :)